# Why wont my "intellect" variable add by 5?

Tags: c++

```
if (checkForRoll == "intellect" && checkForRoll == "Intellect") {//checks for intellect
        intellect = intellect + 5;
    } else if (checkForRoll == "strength" && checkForRoll == "Strength") {
        strength = strength + 5;
    }
    cout << intellect;
```

When I execute this, the intellect int does not add by 5. Why?

Comment: More verbosely than AndreyT: What is the **Type** of checkForRoll.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are requiring your string to equal both intellect and Intellect which is impossible.  Change the "and" (`&&`) to an "or" (`||`).

Answer (score 2):

Your variable checkForRoll can't be 'strength' && 'Strength', it can be 'strength' || 'Strength' however.

Answer (score 2):

CheckForRoll cannot be both "intellect" and "Intellect".

Assuming you are using a `std::string` convert to upppercase, and do one comparision.

```
std:string checkForRoll = "inTeLleCt";

std::transform(checkForRoll.begin() , checkForRoll.end() , checkForRoll.begin(), ::toupper);

if (checkForRoll == "INTELLECT")
{
....
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, see Herb Sutter's presentation of implementing a basic_string specialization that operates in a case-insensitive manner: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm

Answer (score 1):

This will only work of `checkForRoll` is a `string`
If it is a `char*` then you can't test for equality with `==`. You need to use `strcmp()` to compare.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, I suggest you use `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` to convert the string before you compare.  See also `std::transform`.

This simplifies your life by using only one comparison.

"Try it, you'll like it!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace && with ||

P.S. you could also write intellect += 5